# How to set default addressbook via Addin

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I need to change the addressbook a user sees when he writes an email. But I can't find any option to do this.

In general I see 2 ways to solve this problem:
1) Set the default addressbook
2) react when user opens 'Select Names' dialog and modify the initial addresslist

For option 1 I can't find any functions to do this and for option 2 i have only part of a solution.

```cs
foreach (Outlook.AddressList addrList in addrLists)
{
    Outlook.Folder testFolder = addrList.GetContactsFolder() as Outlook.Folder;

    if (Application.Session.CompareEntryIDs(testFolder.EntryID, addressbookID))
    {
        writeLog("passendes Adressbuch gefunden", 4);
        namesDialog.InitialAddressList = addrList;
        namesDialog.Display();
    }
}
```

With this code I can set initial addresslist and show the dialog but I don't know an event that happens when the 'to', 'cc' 'bcc' button is pressed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override the Outlook behavior when the user clicks the To/CC/BCC buttons. `InitialAddressList` property is only for when you explicitly show the address book dialog.

On the MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), you would need to call `IAddrBook.SetDefaultDir` passing the entry id of the container (as well as set the `PR_AB_CHOOSE_DIRECTORY_AUTOMATICALLY` property to false in a profile section).

Outlook Object Model does not expose that funcitonality. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes [RDOAddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).`DefaultAddressList` r/w property.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll have a look at Redemption